# LINQ to get max of nullable datetime from a list

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a list of object models that look like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public Nullable<DateTime> SomeUserTime { get; set; }
}

var List<MyModel> TheList = some list from somewhere
```

I want to get the latest SomeUserTime in the list, knowing that may be the list doesn't contain any value, in which case the output should be null. This is what I have:

```
DateTime? LatestTime = (from x in TheList select x.SomeUserTime).Max();
```

This compiles fine but the sample data doesn't have any null values. Will this also work (ie return null) if none of the elements in the list have a time?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @DanielBrückner: "the sample data doesn't have any null values" so instead of creating new sample data, I just asked a question.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get a compile error about implicitly converting `System.DateTime?` to `System.DateTime`?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: actually, in my code, LatestTime is declared as nullable datetime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it will ignore the `null` values and give you the Max in `DateTime?`.

```
List<DateTime?> list = new List<DateTime?>();
list.Add(new DateTime?());
list.Add(new DateTime(2014,04,15));
DateTime? max = list.Max();
```

and you will get back:

```
max = {15/04/2014 12:00:00 AM}
```

You can also filter out `null` values and then get max like:

```
DateTime LatestTime = (from x in TheList 
                       where x.SomeUserTime != null) //or x.SomeUserTime.HasValue
                       select x.SomeUserTime.Value).Max();
```

The above line would throw an exception if the list is empty. You will get:

```
Sequence contains no elements
```

You can fix it like:

```
DateTime? LatestTime = (from x in TheList 
                        select x.SomeUserTime).Max();
```

If the list is empty then this will give you `null`, or return you the max date if list contains any `DateTime` value. Just **make sure** you are not trying to store the result in `DateTime`, use `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?` and do not access `Value` property of `Nullable<T>` item.

Comment: What if the list only has null values? Will Max be null?

Comment: @frenchie, In that case you will have to use `DateTime? LatestTime = TheList.Select(r=> r.SomeUserTime).Max();` and then it would be null.

Comment: @frenchie, just make sure you are not trying to store the result in `DateTime`, use `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?`. That will give you back `null` if the list is empty.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime? LatestTime = (from x in TheList 
                        select (DateTime?)x.SomeUserTime).Max();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should also work. No sorting is needed

```
TheList.Select(x=>x.SomeUserTime??DateTime.MinValue).Max())
```

Comment: you cant apply ?? to DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

I think  the safest way will be something like this

```
TheList.Select(model=>model.SomeUserTime).OrderByDescending().FirstOrdefault()
```

this will return  a null if your list is empty

Comment: `Max` on Nullable types would return `null` if the List is empty.